# Ember.js: Setter does not fire when bound property changes (trying to implement isChanged property on Ember.Object)

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to implement `isChanged` property on Ember.Object. I've created BaseObject, which my other objects extend:

```
App.BaseObject = Ember.Object.extend({
    isChanged: false,
    changeTime: new Date(),

    set: function (key, value) {
        var ignored = this.get("ignoreProperties") || [];
        ignored.push("isChanged");

        if (!ignored.contains(key)) //contains is my own prototype function on Array
        {
            this._super("isChanged", true);
            this._super("changeTime", new Date());
        }

        this._super(key, value);
    }
});
```

I've got sample child object:

```
App.ChildObject = App.BaseObject.extend({
    text: "DEFAULT TEXT"
});
```

which represents model for page with HBS template:

```
<input type="text" {{bind-attr value="text"}}>
```

Page shows input field with "DEFAULT TEXT" in it, but when I change text in this input field, custom `set` function is not fired. Therefore my `isChanged` property is not set to `true`.

Is there a way to force Ember to run my setter when bound property is changed?

Comment: What is the Ember version?

Comment: I can't provide evidence for this right now, but I remember having a lot of trouble overriding the `set` function because Ember doesn't always use it internally. Maybe that's changed, but if not, it's likely your problem. You might have to consider overriding the `setUnknownProperty` and `unknownProperty` hooks and creating a sort of object proxy. Or you can declare every property you want to watch explicitly.

Comment: I use v1.8.1. I ended up with setting up observer on each property in `init` hook and removing it on `willDestroy`. I'll debug it and post an update, if it works as desired.